# How to modify table cart WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I wonna modify cart-item-data to inline such as:

- color : white
- size : M

[image: First image]

---

I have code below.

[image: Second image]

Comment: Please post code in the question instead of linking to an image of the code. Also you can post regular images right in the question too. In spite of all of that, I can tell you that you need modify the CSS style rules for definition lists.

Comment: <dl class="variation">
 <?php foreach ( $item_data as $data ) : ?>
  <dt class="variation-<?php echo sanitize_html_class( $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $data['key'] ); ?>:</dt>
  <dd class="variation-<?php echo sanitize_html_class( $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $data['display'] ) ); ?></dd>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>

Comment: Please edit the question and add your code there. Code in the comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Go to woocommerce plugin folder and find folder **templates** and go to **cart** folder and find **cart.php** change  table on that file

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is CSS. You need the `dd` and `dt` elements to be inline instead of block level. Something like this might work:

```
dl.variation dt, dl.variation dd {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

It might also *not* work if there is a more specific rule somewhere else in your stylesheets or if something else comes later on in the stylesheets to override this. Impossible for me to say without knowing your theme and WooCommerce setup, but this is a good start.